# Layered Navigation with custom filter

Tags: layered-navigation, product-list

I want to filter Product List Page and I'm using a plugin to filter the collection using the layer class

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::prepareProductCollection()
```

The products are removed but the toolbar is showing a wrong count and the layered navigations has the gap for the products.

I am using Magento 2.4